# After first image add excerpt within the gallery shortcode for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, gallery, shortcode

I have a gallery that is a scrolling collection of the images using this short code

```
[gallery itemtag="div" icontag="span" captiontag="p" link="none" size="full" columns="0"]
```

EXAMPLE OF GALLERY PAGER:

http://rc2.jaywolfe.com/cars-for-sale/2013-toyota-land-cruiser-base-t30061/

Need to add content JUST after/between the first and second image. I've been able to use this or variant of in other applications but since its within a shortcode I'm struggling to get it.

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
[gallery itemtag="div" icontag="span" captiontag="p" link="none" size="full" columns="0"]
        <?php if ($counter % 4 == 3): /* ADD THIS */ ?>
<div>test</div>
<?php endif; ?>

              <?php $counter++ ?>
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding this worked for me. Just added it to my functions.php file and called the new short code as needed.

```
function jw_vdp_gallery() {
    ob_start();
$id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()); // gets the post thumbnail ID
echo do_shortcode('[gallery exclude='.$id.' itemtag="div" icontag="span" captiontag="p" link="none" size="full" columns="0"]');

$output_string = ob_get_contents();  
ob_end_clean();  
return $output_string; 
} 
add_shortcode( 'vdp-gallery', 'jw_vdp_gallery' );
```